# ld : 0711-224 warning : Duplicate symbol (Overriding a System Call in AIX)

Tags: unix, kernel, aix, kernel-extension

I read this article (http://qasim.zaidi.me/2009/05/overriding-system-call-in-aix.html;) about overriding a systemcall in aix;

I wrote two kernel extensions just like the article said "The first kernel extension would merely re-export the original system call with a different name. The second, will actually override the syscall by redefining it, and then call the original one as exported by the first module."

But there is a error when I make the second extension:

```
1> gcc -O2 -maix64 -ffreestanding -o my_syscall.o -c my_syscall.c -D_KERNEL
1> ld -b64 -o my_syscall my_syscall.o -e my_syscall_init -bI:/home/rabbitte/output/test_system/my_syscall.exp -bI:/usr/lib/kernex.exp -lsys -lcsys 
1>ld : 0711-224 warning : Duplicate symbol: .getpid
1> ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

The file "/home/rabbitte/output/test_system/my_syscall.exp" is the export file of the first extension.
I don't understand the what the "Duplicate symbol: .getpid" means. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Let me read the article and play with it some.  Very often, the duplicate symbol warnings can be ignored.  Is the exit status of ld 0?  i.e. echo $? as the next command after the ld.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the file “kernex.exp” also include the symbol “getpid”. I should comment the getpid in file kernex.exp.

Comment: I read the article.  He talks about two kernel extensions.  I suspect you get the duplicate error on the one that defines the new getpid.  Yes... you need to not say that you will get getpid from the kernel because you are not.  I would create a custom import file (which may be empty) and add in the symbols from kernexp that the second module needs.  You can also do this trickery with libraries put into LIBPATH and not have kernel extensions at all.  ptrace does this.  I also *think* there is a way to do it in one step.  The linker is very versatile.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done any of this, so this might not be sufficient to solve your problem, but your linker line has two `-bI` options. It should be `-bI` for the AIX kernex.exp, and `-bE` for your `exp` file according to the docs you point to.

Comment: Thanks. Kernex.exp is the system export file. And "kernex.exp" is also a file that was exported by the first kernel extension.So both of these files need use -bI.